# Internal 500 error on return view()

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to return View in a new window page but I always get an internal 500 error..the issue is in the controller but I do not seem to find out how to resolve the issue..

JavaScript

```
//other codes
{
 url: 'Index/Booklist',
 method: 'POST',
 success: function(a) {
    window.open(Index/Booklist);
 }, 
 fail: function(a)
    // other codes 
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Booklist() {
 ViewData["test"] = "some value"
 return View(); 
 // I want to send data from Controller to View but it keeps giving an internal 500 error 
}
```

View

```
<head>
//added <script></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p> to receive data from controller </p> @ViewData["test"]
</body>
```

Comment: What do your apache logs / error logs say? There'll be far more information in there.

Comment: open console ,  see the response and post the error, if you just say `500 internal error`, no one is going to help because there are many causes if 500 error .

Comment: @ScottMcGready @J Santosh I checked the console and it says "POST http://localhost/App/Index/Booklist 500 (Internal Server Error)" and I hit the failure message too..

Comment: ... and the error logs?

Comment: No error logs @ScottMcGready

Comment: Then set up error logging, it'll clearly explain what's going on and will give you way more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I will add in later! And I found the issue already! It is to change to Content("success"); instead of VIew(); But now I am trying to see how to pass in value from the javascript to View....@ScottMcGready @J Santosh

Comment: I'd recommend answering your own question then. There's far too many open questions without answers on this site. You can answer your own question and even mark it as correct :)

Comment: Might be late but I answered the question :) @ScottMcGready

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as correct so that others can see. Glad it got sorted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript

```
//other codes
{
 url: 'Index/Booklist',
 method: 'POST',
 success: function(a) {
    window.open(Index/Booklist);
 }, 
 fail: function(a)
    // other codes 
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Booklist() {
 ViewData["test"] = "some value"
 return Content("success"); // changed here 
}
```

View

```
<head>
//added <script></script>
</head>     
<body>
 <p> to receive data from controller </p> @ViewData["test"]
</body>
```

Basically I changed the View(); to Content("success"). (shown above)

But I found out that you can use View(); too which is shown below.
It is to remove the POST method and url (cause of error)

JavaScript

```
//other codes
{
    // all the other codes were removed POST method and url which is causing the error 
    window.open(Index/Booklist);
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Booklist() {
 ViewData["test"] = "some value"
 return View();
}
```

View

```
<head>
//added <script></script>
</head>     
<body>
 <p> to receive data from controller </p> @ViewData["test"]
</body>
```